# Factorize polynomials function

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots, factoring, quartics

**The task was:**

Find the set of zeros (roots) of the following function $$f(x)=x^4-6x^2-8x+24$$

**What I did:**
I found the possibles roots $$\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm6,\pm8,\pm12,\pm24  $$
and I found that X=2 but I cannot get the other 3 roots

Comment: Did you divide $f(x)$ by $x - 2$ to determine the other factor?

Comment: Do a polynomial division with (x-2), since you know it is a root.

Comment: I tried but 24 remains ,and I don't know why , if any one can solve it with explain because I have just got that class on school and I want to understand it well

Comment: When you divide, make sure you write $f(x)$ in the form $$f(x) = x^4 + 0x^3 - 6x^2 - 8x + 24$$

Comment: same problem @N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You found that $x = 2$ is a root of $f(x) = x^4 - 6x^2 - 8x + 24$.  This means $x - 2$ is a factor.  Dividing $f(x)$ by $x - 2$ yields 
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = x^4 - 6x^2 - 8x + 24\\
     & = x^3(x - 2) + 2x^3 - 6x^2 - 8x + 24\\
     & = x^3(x - 2) + 2x^2(x - 2) + 4x^2 - 6x^2 - 8x + 24\\
     & = x^3(x - 2) + 2x^2(x - 2) - 2x^2 - 8x + 24\\
     & = x^3(x - 2) + 2x^2(x - 2) - 2x(x - 2) - 4x - 8x + 24\\
     & = x^3(x - 2) + 2x^2(x - 2) - 2x(x - 2) - 12x + 24\\
     & = x^3(x - 2) + 2x^2(x - 2) - 2x(x - 2) - 12(x - 2)\\
     & = (x - 2)(x^3 + 2x^2 - 2x - 12)
\end{align*}
Now apply the Rational Roots Theorem and Factor Theorem to 
$$g(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 - 2x - 12$$
to find another root, which may be the same as the first root.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4-6x^2-8x+24=(x^2+5)^2-16x^2-8x-1=(x^2+5)^2-(4x+1)^2=$$
$$=(x^2-4x+4)(x^2+4x+6)=(x-2)^2(x^2+4x+6),$$
which gives the answer:
$$\{2,-2+\sqrt{2}i,-2-\sqrt2i\}.$$

Comment: What intuition or observation would lead to that first step?

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs I want to use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ and I made it. I used the following way. For all real $k$ we have $x^4-6x^2-8x+24=(x^2-k)^2-((6-2k)x^2+8x+x^2-24))$. Now easy to see that for $k=-5$ we have $(6-2k)x^2+8x+x^2-24=16x^2+8x+1=(4x+1)^2$ and we got a possibility to use the formula $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.